# Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set on Azure Devops - predefined variables not recognised

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine

I built a Scale Set(Windows) and I can run simple commands successfully on my Azure Devops Custom Agent Pool, with a custom VM based on Windows 19 Server Core based on this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#create-the-scale-set).

However, when I try to access any Azure Devops [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) in any of my tasks they are not recognised. For example executing:

```
- job: jobname
  timeoutInMinutes: 200
  pool:
    name: poolname
    vmImage: vmname
  steps:
  - powershell: |
        echo "    Branch: $(Build.Branch)"
```

Gives me:

```
Build.Branch : The term 'Build.Branch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
```

If I check my Scale Set in the Azure Portal, the extension `Microsoft.Azure.DevOps.Pipelines.Agent` is successfully installed and upgraded onto the instances.

The same exact task and Powershell works fine if it runs in a Windows provided agent such as `windows-2019`. Any ideas why this error occurs? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Well, for starters, `Build.Branch` **isn't** one of the pre-defined variables.

Comment: that was it , thanks @DanielMann , it still weird because I can 100% confirm that the same code works on the 'windows-2019' agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tested the shell script task on my VMSS Windows-2019 agent, it can correctly print the value of the predefined variables in pipeline. I did not get any error.

I tried the VMSS created via executing the related Azure CLI on Azure Cloud Shell, and manual created on Azure Portal web UI, both of them can work fine without any error.

Please check with the following steps:

1. Try the VMSS in different pipelines, different projects to see if the same issue occurs.
2. Try creating a new VMSS (you can try manual creation) to see if the issue also occurs on the new VMSS.
3. Check if there is any syntax or format issue in your pipeline definition (YAML file). Below is a simple pipeline as reference, I tested it on my side and it can work fine.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: JobA
  displayName: 'Job A'
  pool: 'My VMSS Agents Pool'
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Show predefined variables'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        Write-Host "Build.SourceBranch = $(Build.SourceBranch)"
        echo "Build.SourceBranchName = $(Build.SourceBranchName)"

- job: JobB
  displayName: 'Job B'
  pool: 'My VMSS Agents Pool'
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Show predefined variables'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        Write-Host "Build.Repository.Name = $(Build.Repository.Name)"
        echo "Build.Repository.ID = $(Build.Repository.ID)"
```

**[UPDATED]**

I also have tested the variable '**`Build.Branch`**' on Microsoft Hosted agent windows-2019 and my VMSS, it worked on neither Microsoft Hosted agent windows-2019 nor my VMSS. As `@DanielMann` has mentioned, '**`Build.Branch`**' is not a predefined variable for Azure Pipelines. So, it is correct that it would be not recognized.

[image]

You commented that the variable '**`Build.Branch`**' can work fine in your pipeline when using Microsoft Hosted agent windows-2019, could you please share us with the related pipeline run logs or screenshot to show this? Just like as the GIF image I show above.

In addition, whether the Microsoft Hosted agent windows-2019 and you VMSS run the same pipeline? If they run different pipelines, please check if you have defined a custom variable '**`Build.Branch`**' on the pipeline which runs on the Microsoft Hosted agent windows-2019.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please see the comment on my question? I basically got it to work with `Build.SourceBranch` in my new VMSS agent but not `Build.Branch` which works fine in an existing Microsoft Hosted agent `windows-2019`

Comment: Hi @and_apo, you commented using the variable `Build.Branch` can output the branch name on Microsoft Hosted agent `windows-2019`, but not on your VMSS. However, I also have tested it on Microsoft Hosted agent `windows-2019` and my VMSS, it worked neither on Microsoft Hosted agent `windows-2019` nor on my VMSS. See the attached GIF image in my answer.

Comment: Yes Build.Branch was defined as a separate variable. Thanks for the help